# Sharing Parameters With Multiple SSRS Reports

Tags: ssrs-2008, reporting-services

I'm trying to share a set of parameters with several reports.

Is it possible to do that?

I currently have to create a set of parameters for each individual report. This creates duplicates of the same data, and makes it harder to maintain.

I am using SSRS 2008 R2.

Any help or direction on this would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks (^_^)

Comment: can you give me more information?

Comment: @masoud: I have the same set of parameters, example: a list of colours that I need to use in different reports, the list of colours is exactly the same in each report. I hope that clarifies it a bit. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

no, it is not possible because the parameters are directly linked to reports, like data sets. There are, on SSRS 2008 **R2**, `shared data sets`, the same way you have `shared data sources`. Maybe with them, you could try to do something like that (don't known, just guessing)